# Parsing error on app.yaml with AppEngine Maven plugin

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gcloud, maven-gae-plugin, appengine-maven-plugin

I am trying to run  a local (developer machine) Java AppEngine Standard Env server using the new Maven plugin (`com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.2.1`) with Google Cloud SDK [148.0.1]. The command is `mvn appengine:run -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

When I do that, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'`.

```
  --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.2.1:run (default-cli) @ tradeos ---
Mar 28, 2017 2:18:45 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: C:\python27_x64\python.exe c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py F:\freightos-maven\tradeos\target\tradeos-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --dev_appserver_log_level=debug
 GCLOUD: Traceback (most recent call last):
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 101, in <module>
 GCLOUD:     _run_file(__file__, globals())
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
 GCLOUD:     execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1041, in <module>
 GCLOUD:     main()
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1037, in main
 GCLOUD:     dev_server.stop()
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 845, in stop
 GCLOUD:     metrics.GetMetricsLogger().Stop()
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\metrics.py", line 117, in Stop
 GCLOUD:     total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())
 GCLOUD: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

The SDK code shows  that this happens when trying to *stop* the metrics module after it failed to initialize. So, I edited the SDK to give hard-coded values to let the dev_appserver continue and so expose the actual error.

That's when I started getting a parsing error while reading `appengine-web.xml`. See below.

```
<<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.2.1:run (default-cli) < package @ tradeos <<<
 --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.2.1:run (default-cli) @ tradeos ---
Mar 28, 2017 12:10:34 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: C:\python27_x64\python.exe c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py F:\freightos-maven\tradeos\target\tradeos-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --dev_appserver_log_level=debug
 GCLOUD: Traceback (most recent call last):
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 101, in <module>
 GCLOUD:     _run_file(__file__, globals())
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
 GCLOUD:     execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1041, in <module>
 GCLOUD:     main()
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1029, in main
 GCLOUD:     dev_server.start(options)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 754, in start
 GCLOUD:     env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 851, in __init__
 GCLOUD:     env_variables)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 131, in __init__
 GCLOUD:     self._config_path)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 438, in _parse_configuration
 GCLOUD:     config, files = self._parse_java_configuration(configuration_path)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 485, in _parse_java_configuration
 GCLOUD:     config = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(app_yaml_str)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 2369, in LoadSingleAppInfo
 GCLOUD:     listener.Parse(app_info)
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 227, in Parse
 GCLOUD:     self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 173, in _HandleEvents
 GCLOUD:     for event in events:
 GCLOUD:   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\google\cloud sdk\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 213, in _GenerateEventParameters
 GCLOUD:     raise yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError(e)
 GCLOUD: google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: while scanning for the next token
 GCLOUD: found character '\t' that cannot start any token
 GCLOUD:   in "<string>", line 11929, column 1:
```

What I tried:

- Older versions of the Maven plugin (1.0.0). same results
- I downloaded the sample app guestbook and tried running it, it worked
  fine. My app has the same structure as the sample.
- Copied the `appengine-web.xml` from the sample into my project, still
  the same errors.
- The server is working fine with the old Maven plugin delivered with the Java SDK `com.google.appengine:com.google.appengine:1.9.50`

`pom.xml` follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion><!-- REQUIRED -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tradeos</groupId>
        <artifactId>freightos-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../freightos-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>tradeos</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging><!-- REQUIRED -->

    <properties>
        <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.2.1</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.133.v201611104</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml><!-- REQUIRED -->
    </properties>

    <prerequisites><!-- Optional, but suggested -->
        <maven>3.3.9</maven><!-- Recommended minimum maven version -->
    </prerequisites>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/UnitTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Used to add additional sources -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>lib/gwt</source>
                                <source>lib/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!--Override compiler and java version -->
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <!-- Use java jdt compiler instead of maven java compiler(javac) -->
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                        <version>${jdt.compiler.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- GWT maven plugin to do GWT compile -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceLevel>1.7</sourceLevel>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <localWorkers>3</localWorkers>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx3072m</extraJvmArgs>
                    <modules>
                        <module>com.tradeos.Tradeos</module>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/lib/libs</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>easypost-java-2.0.9.jar</include>
                                <include>gwt-servlet-deps.jar</include>
                                <include>org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.5.0.jar</include>
                                <include>poi-3.14-20160629.jar</include>
                                <include>gwt-visualization.jar</include>
                                <include>pdfcrowd.jar</include>
                                <include>ip2c.jar</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                 <configuration><!--
                    <jvmFlags>-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1G</jvmFlags>
                    <maxModuleInstances>1</maxModuleInstances>
                    <port>8888</port>
                    <startSuccessTimeout>0</startSuccessTimeout> -->
                    <devAppserverLogLevel>debug</devAppserverLogLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.1.v20170120</version>
                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <host>localhost</host>
                        <port>8888</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <classifier>full</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tradeos</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfcrowd</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/libs/pdfcrowd.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tradeos</groupId>
            <artifactId>gails</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.allen-sauer.gwt.dnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dnd</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudmonitoring</artifactId>
            <version>v2beta2-rev42-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add itextpdf java jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/gwt/guava-gwt-18.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.advanced-gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>advanced-components</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/gwt/advanced-components-2.0.7.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.moxieapps.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/libs/org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.5.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POI library version 3.14 modified to be compatible with appengine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>poi-3.14-20160629</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/libs/poi-3.14-20160629.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>easypost</groupId>
            <artifactId>easypost-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/libs/easypost-java-2.0.9.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gwt.servlet.deps</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/libs/gwt-servlet-deps.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maps3</artifactId>
            <version>0.1a</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/gwt/gwt-maps3-0.1a.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: @joshua-fox has this been fixed by using the Dev Appserver v1 in the com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.0-rc1 ?

Comment: @loosebazooka yes, version 1.3.0-rc1 fixed this.

Comment: @loosebazooka, when you say that  1.3.0-rc1 uses Dev Appserver v1 , are you saying that this Cloud-SDK based Maven plugin is moving from use plain Jetty to using the old dev appserver, part of the old Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, tabs were coming from `web.xml`. That is a bug in the tool, as it should handle legal characters like this, but a workaround is to replace tabs with spaces in `web.xml`  and `appengine-web.xml`.

Comment: The com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.2.1 plugin reads all the xml files and turn them into yaml, so if you are facing this issue as well check all your xml files for \t characters in this case it was web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same error with google app engine using cmd,
for this error is itself in the app.yaml file only.

- you could either check for any changes in leading slashes in url
- for me removing `application: application_name` did the job...although that may
  be required if you are not deploying app locally

I am too looking forward for an alternative solution.